# Error running NodeJS spawn after execSync

Tags: node.js, exec, spawn

I have the following code:

> execSync('ls -la').toString();
>
> spawn('ls', ['-la'], {
> detached: true,
> stdio: 'ignore',
> });

and the spawn command is not working, but if replace **spawn** by:

> exec('ls -la')

is working.

Why **spawn** not work after I run **execSync**.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,

Waldo

Comment: "not working" is not a proper problem description. What is the current behavior, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: "not working": means that spawn is not executing the command, if I remove the line execSync, then spawn execute the command